# jQuery tablesorter with specific date

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

I want to use jQuery tablesorter to sort a date column with the following format: `18:44:12 17/06/2012`

any ideas how?

Comment: here is the plugin site: http://tablesorter.com/docs/

Comment: plugin docs show how to create  custom sort parser

Comment: and how do I create that kind of custom sort parser for date?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First issue is parsing your date text to a format that javascript `Date object` will recognize. Once converted to a date, plugin will treat a date as numeric sort type. Here's a working parser for your format.

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/H9u7C/1/

```
$.tablesorter.addParser({

    // set a unique id
    id: 'changeToDate',
    is: function(s) {
        // return false so this parser is not auto detected
        return false;
    },

    format: function(s) {
        var a = $.trim(s).split(' ');
        var time = a[0];
        var dateParts = a[1].split('/');
        var dateText = [dateParts[1], dateParts[0], dateParts[2]].join('/') + ' ' + time;
        var dateObj = new Date(dateText);
        return dateObj;

    },

    type: 'numeric'
});
```

Usage is as outlined in custom parser demo on plugin site

http://tablesorter.com/docs/example-parsers.html

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem with tablesorter 2.0.
Dates dd/mm/yy are wrong at line 982...

```
s = s.replace(/(\d{1,2})[\/\-](\d{1,2})[\/\-](\d{2})/, "$1/$2/$3");
```

is wrong, the correct is

```
s = s.replace(/(\d{1,2})[\/\-](\d{1,2})[\/\-](\d{2})/, "$3/$2/$1");
```

My  ts.addParser({id: "shortDate"...  is:

```
ts.addParser({
        id: "shortDate",
        is: function (s) {
            return /\d{1,2}[\/\-]\d{1,2}[\/\-]\d{2,4}/.test(s);
        }, format: function (s, table) {
            var c = table.config;
            s = s.replace(/\-/g, "/");
            if (c.dateFormat == "us") {
                // reformat the string in ISO format
                s = s.replace(/(\d{1,2})[\/\-](\d{1,2})[\/\-](\d{4})/, "$3/$1/$2");
            } else if (c.dateFormat == "uk") {
                // reformat the string in ISO format
                s = s.replace(/(\d{1,2})[\/\-](\d{1,2})[\/\-](\d{4})/, "$3/$2/$1");
            } else if (c.dateFormat == "dd/mm/yy" || c.dateFormat == "dd-mm-yy") {
                s = s.replace(/(\d{1,2})[\/\-](\d{1,2})[\/\-](\d{2})/, "$3/$2/$1");
            } else if (c.dateFormat == "dd/mm/yyyy" || c.dateFormat == "dd-mm-yyyy") {
                s = s.replace(/(\d{1,2})[\/\-](\d{1,2})[\/\-](\d{4})/, "$3/$2/$1");
            }
            return $.tablesorter.formatFloat(new Date(s).getTime());
        }, type: "numeric"
    });
```

I have add dd/mm/yyyy case. For the date, i don't know... :(

You must put dateFormat: "dd/mm/yyyy" as parameter.